# How would I get output from system call to textview

Tags: mono, monodevelop

Hey guys I am new to the C#/Mono programming side of things, but I would like to get the output from a system call to be direct to the textview. How would I do that? Here is what I have for far:

```
protected void OnButton2Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Init ();
    Window win = new Window ("System Information");
    win.SetDefaultSize (600,400);
    TextView view = new Gtk.TextView ();
    TextBuffer buffer = view.Buffer;

    win.Add (view);
    win.ShowAll ();
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo("dmidecode","-t system"){ RedirectStandardOutput = true, UseShellExecute = false };
    var proc = new Process { StartInfo = info, EnableRaisingEvents = true };
    proc.Start ();
    Console.WriteLine (proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ().ToString());
    buffer.Text = proc.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Doesn't simply `buffer.Text = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` work?

Comment: Yes. buffer.Text = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); works. Just found out that once ReadToEnd finishes its job that the info is no longer available after that.